# Pagination method tutorial for SwiftUI code throws errors

Tags: swiftui, pagination

I am trying to learn how to make working pagination for a long list and my friend recommended this tutorial:
https://medium.com/swlh/easy-pagination-in-swiftui-da9e1fe3e25e

I copied the code, but I get some errors like

```
Cannot use instance member 'currentPage' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Cannot use instance member 'perPage' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

The author said that "MemberListCell and ActivityIndicator are custom views."

I tried to mock them with using some other website (since I couldn't get JSON for the one that author shared), but it only threw even more errors.

Could you help me mock the missing code, so I can check how this pagination solution works?

EDIT: I paste the code, since the article is paywalled:

The list file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Members: View {
    @ObservedObject var memberData = MemberData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                // 1. Members
                ForEach(memberData.members) { member in
                    MembersListCell(member: member)
                }
                
                // 2. Activity Indicator. Last element of list.
                // Show activity spinner if backend has more data.
                // Its onAppear method is used to load new members. Pagination done.
                if memberData.membersListFull == false {
                    ActivityIndicator()
                    .onAppear {
                        memberData.fetchMembers()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Members")
        }
    }
}
```

MembersData file:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class MemberData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var members = [Member]()
    
    // Tells if all records have been loaded. (Used to hide/show activity spinner)
    var membersListFull = false
    // Tracks last page loaded. Used to load next page (current + 1)
    var currentPage = 0
    // Limit of records per page. (Only if backend supports, it usually does)
    let perPage = 20
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://testURL.com?page=\(currentPage+1)&perPage=\(perPage)")!
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    func fetchMembers() {
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap { $0.data }
            .decode(type: [Member].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .catch { _ in Just(self.members) }
            .sink { [weak self] in
                self?.currentPage += 1
                self?.members.append(contentsOf: $0)
                // If count of data received is less than perPage value then it is last page. 
                if $0.count < perPage {
                    self?.membersListFull = true
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're linking to a site where articles appear behind a paywall after a certain number of views. Please include the relevant code here that needs to be debugged.

Comment: Done @jnpdx. The tutorial has only this note: 
"MemberListCell and ActivityIndicator are custom views."

There is no information about API Keys anywhere either, but I don't know if they are needed here.
The URL they provide is private and I couldn't get JSON for it, but when I changed it to the one I knew JSON structure for, I also got errors...

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `MembersListCell(member: member)` with `Text(member.somevariable)` some variable being any available variable in the model and then replace `ActivityIndicator()` with `ProgressView()`. Then try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) it seems like you are missing the basics.

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum. I am doing 100 days with SwiftUI by Paul Hudson, so I will get there in some time (I think).

Comment: @loremipsum I applied your solution here and now Swift gives errors on [Member]() in MembersData file. What should I switch [Member]() with?

Comment: That you will have to create based on the JSON that is provided by the website [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io) makes it easy just paste the JSON there and it will give you most of the code you need. Make sure you understand what is going on though, QuickType is a great resource to start but you should understand what the code means.

Comment: A'ight will do my best @loremipsum. Thanks a lot! I have some experience working with JSON code in Swift already. Perhaps I will be able to do this one '^^

Comment: @loremipsum, I cannot read JSON from the URL from the tutorial, since it needs a login but it disallows to create an account.
I have reframed this question entirely with another url that I know working keys for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70968269/swift-pagination-method-from-medium-tutorial-throws-errors

Comment: Replace Item with firstName in you other question for one error. Item is a type not a variable. Also, like I said at the beginning you should look at the SwiftUI tutorials if the 100 days of … hasn’t taught you how to iterate through an array in the last 11 days it is the wrong tutorial, you need to take that one after you learn the basics. I also suggest the learn to code Playgrounds that are on iPad and Mac I believe. You are traveling a much harder path by skipping the basics.

Comment: Don’t get discouraged either usually when I say something like the above to someone they come back saying I discouraged them but I don’t mean it that way. I just see that there is a gap in knowledge.

Comment: I won't get discouraged, @loremipsum. Thank you for your invalueable input!
Paul haven't covered ForEach syntax as of yet.
I thought I could tackle this problem after I finished all the basics from 100 Days of SwiftUI. Need to learn more :)